# Disable Windows Control Focus

Tags: c#, wpf

Im making a custom UI using WPF.

Currently I am not using Blend, but if I have to I will learn how to use it.

Im trying to remove the effect that happens when you hover over a control, this is what it looks like without hover:

[image: no hover]

and with hover:

[image: hover]

Does anyone know how I can remove this?

Comment: looks like a case of excessive customizations

Comment: could you show xaml for login button, please?

Comment: <Button Margin="12,95,0,0" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" AllowDrop="False" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" MouseEnter="button1_MouseEnter">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/myProject;component/Images/LoginBtn.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="None" />
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

Answer (score 3):

Controls have VisualStates in WPF and Silverlight. If you are using default textbox control it has VisualState for MouseOver:

```
<vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF99C1E2" Duration="0"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </vsm:VisualState>
```

My suggestion for you is go to this website:[TextBox Default Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Get the default template for textbox then remove the visualstate for MouseOver. Or you can do it for any template like this.

Hope you got the idea!